# Why is strcpy(strerror(errno),"Hello") not copying "Hello",but {ptr=strerror(errno);strcpy(ptr,"Hello");} does?

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy, string.h, strerror

Please explain what's going on in the following program.

I checked out the addresses returned by `strerror(errno)` at the beginning and end of the program and it confirms that it returns the same address each time.Then once sure of this,in first case I proceeded to assign that same address to `ptr` and then copy a string `"Hello"` to it using `strcpy()`.In case II,I tried to copy `"Hello"` directly to the address returned by `strerror(errno)`.I had odd findings.I'll appreciate if you explain the following:

In case one,I copied `"Hello"` to `ptr` and it is successful as in the subsequent `printf()`,`ptr` prints `Hello`.But then, when I passed `strerror(errno)` instead of `ptr` to `printf()`,it prints the old error message.How is it possible that `ptr` points to one message but `strerror(errno)` points to another message when both addresses are same?I verified both addresses are same and I expect that copying `"Hello"` to `ptr` should be same as copying it to the return of `strerror(errno)`.To doubly check this discrepancy,then I tried to copy `"Hello"` directly to `strerror(errno)` but it doesn't work this time too and it prints the same old error string.But the surprising thing is,at this point too, I verified again that the addresses `ptr` and `strerror(errno)` are indeed same all along!! How is it possible?If they are same how are they pointing to different strings?One to `"Hello"` and other to the old custom error message?

Please explain the reason behind this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{ char *ptr;
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen ("missingfile.txt","r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    printf ("%s\n",strerror(errno));
    printf("\n%p",strerror(errno));  //Initial address

    //Case1:
    ptr=strerror(errno);
    strcpy(ptr,"Hello");
    printf("\n%s",ptr);  //Prints Hello
    printf("\n%s",strerror(errno)); //Still prints old message


    //Case2:
    strcpy(strerror(errno),"Hello"); //Doesn't copy Hello there
    printf("\n%s",strerror(errno)); //Still prints old message


    printf("\n%p",strerror(errno)); //Address same as it was at start
    printf("\n%p",ptr);  //same address as above statement


  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
No such file or directory

00032508
Hello
No such file or directory
No such file or directory
00032508
00032508
```

Comment: You cannot do this, why are you trying to do this? It make no sense.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel Actually I had read that `The returned pointer points to a statically allocated string,  which shall not be modified by the program`.I was only tinkering with it and was surprised to see how the same address can be of two different strings,one `Hello` and other the custom error message.`ptr` has `Hello` while the return of `strerror(errno)` has other message ,but both `ptr` and `strerror(errno)` are the same address all along!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
//Case2:
strcpy(strerror(errno),"Hello"); //Doesn't copy Hello there
printf("\n%s",strerror(errno));
```

Your second call to `strerror` in the `printf` overwrites what you copied.

This is bad-form, all the way around.

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror):

> This string must not be modified by the application, but may be modified by a subsequent call to **strerror()**.

So while the function doesn't return a `const` pointer, it should nevertheless **not** be modified, and that includes copying to it.

The `strerror` may in fact have a `static` buffer, which is the reason you get the same pointer returned from it.

Comment: But how then I managed to copy to that string address indirectly using `ptr`?I managed to copy as printing `ptr` shows,but surprisingly, it doesn't show the same result when I pass `strerror(errno)` as argument to `printf()` even though I have used `ptr=strerror(errno)` and doubly verified before and again both addresses are same.

Comment: Even more authoritative, the standard says "The strerror function returns a pointer to the string, the contents of which are locale-
specific. **The array pointed to shall not be modified by the program**, but may be overwritten by a subsequent call to the strerror function." A "shall not" violation that means undefined behaviour.